# Why I can't run "npm run sass"?

Tags: css, node.js, npm, sass, package

When I run "npm run sass" I got an error. Please check my screenshot [npm run sass screnshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spagL.jpg)

Comment: Have you installed the node-sass package?

Comment: npm install -g node-sass

Comment: I already install node package

Answer (score 0):

If it's not installed globally, you might have to run it from your `node_modules` folder: `./node_modules/.bin/node-sass`.